# Conservative extenstion, identifying objects of different type

Tags: logic, soft-question, foundations

In a comment [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/), Terence Tao says:

> in practice we often “abuse notation” by identifying objects of one type with another, e.g. identifying the natural number 3 with the integer +3, the rational 3/1, and the real 3.0; this is technically a violation of the usual laws of typed first-order logic, but can be justified by passing to a suitable conservative extension of the original mathematical theory

How can one construct this conservative extension in which one identifies these objects of different type? Can one formalize Tao's idea?

Comment: We consider $\mathbb{N}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the obvious way, and $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ in the obvsious way. Is this perhaps what is meant by a 'conservative extension'?

Comment: @user259242: Not really, no; *conservative extension* is a technical term in mathematical logic. There's a brief discussion [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_extension) that at least gives the basic idea.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see. I should have done a search on this phrase before hazarding a guess. In this case, I have nothing to contribute as this is far afield of my area. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this to go from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ — or, more accurately, from a theory of the natural numbers to a theory of the integers (the concept of "conservative extension," which you referred to, is a syntactic notion referring to sentences and theories, not a semantic notion referring to models). This is based on the construction of integers as equivalence classes of ordered pairs of natural numbers.

Start with the first-order theory of Peano arithmetic.  There are various slightly different ways of defining it (all equivalent), but let's construe PA as a theory in the language $\mathscr{L}$ containing constant symbols for $0$ and $1,$ a two-place relation symbol $\ge,$ and two two-place function symbols $+$ and $\cdot.$

For any formula $\varphi$ in our language, define $\varphi^*$ by induction on formulas as follows:

1. If $\varphi$ is atomic, then $\varphi^*$ is $\varphi.$
2. If $\varphi$ is $\,\lnot \psi,\,$ $\varphi_1\lor\varphi_2,$ or $\,\varphi_1\land\varphi_2,$ then $\varphi^*$ is $\lnot (\psi^*),\,$ $\varphi_1^*\lor\varphi_2^*,$ or $\,\varphi_1^*\land\varphi_2^*,$ respectively.
3. If $\varphi$ is $\exists x\,\psi,$ then $\varphi^*$ is $\exists x\,(x\ge 0 \land \psi^*).$
4. If $\varphi$ is $\forall x\,\psi,$ then $\varphi^*$ is $\forall x\,(x\ge 0 \rightarrow \psi^*).$

Consider the following theory $T$ in the language $\mathscr{L};$ $\,T$ is intended to be a theory of the integers. $T$ contains the following axioms:

1. $\,\varphi^*$ for every $\varphi$ that is an axiom of PA.
2. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x\ge 0 \,\land\, y\ge 0 \rightarrow (\exists z)(x=y+z).$
   (Existence of all integers—really just needed for $y\gt x.)$
3. $(\forall x)(\exists y)(\exists z)(y \ge 0 \,\land\, z\ge 0 \,\land\, x+z=y).\;$
   (Every integer can be written as the difference of two natural numbers.)
4. $(\forall x_1)(\forall y_1)(\forall z_1)(\forall x_2)(\forall y_2)(\forall z_2)\big((x_1+z_1=y_1 \,\land\, x_2+z_2=y_2)\rightarrow(x_1=x_2\iff y_1+z_2=y_2+z_1)\big).\;$
   (Equality of integers.)
5. $(\forall x_1)(\forall y_1)(\forall z_1)(\forall x_2)(\forall y_2)(\forall z_2)\big((x_1+z_1=y_1 \,\land\, x_2+z_2=y_2)\rightarrow(x_1 \ge x_2\iff y_1+z_2 \ge y_2+z_1)\big).\;$
   (Comparison of integers.)
6. $(\forall x_1)(\forall y_1)(\forall z_1)(\forall x_2)(\forall y_2)(\forall z_2)\big((x_1+z_1=y_1 \,\land\, x_2+z_2=y_2)\rightarrow (x_1+x_2)+(z_1+z_2)=y_1+y_2\big).\;$ 
   (Addition of integers.)
7. $(\forall x_1)(\forall y_1)(\forall z_1)(\forall x_2)(\forall y_2)(\forall z_2)\big((x_1+z_1=y_1 \,\land\, x_2+z_2=y_2)\rightarrow (x_1\cdot x_2)+(y_1\cdot z_2 + y_2\cdot z_1)=y_1\cdot y_2 + z_1\cdot z_2\big).\;$
   (Multiplication of integers.)

(In 4-7 above, you can restrict $y_1, y_2, z_1,$ and $z_2$ to be greater than or equal to $0$ if you prefer, in the interest of conceptual parsimony, but it makes the sentences physically longer, so I didn't write them that way.)

The integers with the standard operations form a model of $T.$

If $M$ is any model of $T,$ then the submodel of $M$ consisting of all $x$ such that $\,M\models (x\ge 0)\;$ is a model of PA.

Moreover, if $N$ is any model of PA, then you can construct a model $M$ of $T$ whose members are equivalence classes of ordered pairs from $N,$ in the usual way.  $N$ is then isomorphic to the appropriate submodel of $M,$ just as one would expect.

These two operations (extending a model of PA to a model of $T,$ and going from a model of $T$ to a submodel satisfying PA) are inverses of one another.

Finally, $T$ is a conservative extension of PA in the sense that all of this can be proven syntactically: For any sentence $\varphi$ in the language $\mathscr{L,}$ $\,\text{PA}\vdash\varphi$ iff $T\vdash \phi^*$ (and $\phi^*$ here is the sentence which means precisely that $\varphi$ is true when all its variables are restricted to values $\ge 0.)$

You can do the same sort of construction to go from the integers to the rational numbers.

However, the real numbers are more complicated; it can be done, but you need to include in your formal theory sets of rational numbers (for use as Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences), so it's more complicated.  (Moreover, I'm not sure that Peano arithmetic is really the best starting point for the reals, unless you're interested in knowing which parts of analysis can actually be done "in" PA, rather than in, say, ZFC or even second-order arithmetic.)

Comment: In your opinion, is this what Terry Tao had in mind? His quote talks about *typed* first-order logic, so perhaps we could use types instead of a predicate (in this case $x \geq 0$) to carve out the subtype. I am afraid this sort of thing cannot be used in practice (imagine the working mathematician who performs these sorts of identifications left and right all over the place). Proof assistants need to perform these identifications all the time, and they use different mechanisms (essentially they insert coercions to make sense of what the user wrote).

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think he had in mind something like this. The theories here aren't formally typed--I think they're elaborate enough without adding explicit types. I had thought of writing this up using a new predicate instead of using "\ge 0", but it would have made everything even longer. But this specifically shows how you can have a first-order theory of the integers as essentially equivalence classes of ordered pairs of natural numbers, with the natural numbers embedded canonically, and with the first-order theories of the two being the same (under the appropriate translations).

Comment: @AndrejBauer As for the working mathematician, I think this is a formalization of the identification that a mathematician would make between integers and equivalence classes of ordered pairs of natural numbers (representing a difference). At any given time, you're thinking of one point of view, but you can switch between the viewpoints whenever you want. Of course, formalizations tend to be unwieldy, and this one is no exception.

Comment: I agree this is the natural way of constructing the integers (or a ring from a semiring in general). Based on my experience with actual formalization of mathematics in proof assistants, I wuld say this is a good first attempt, but in practice one needs to accomodate for an unbounded number of possible identifications, and ones that are not known in advance, or are parametrized, or are used only locally in a given proof, etc. I think there's a real question here on how to do this sort of thing. Type theory does not have the final answer either.

Comment: Tao seems to work in a set theory where the naturals are primitive and where the integers are equivalence classes of ordered pairs of natural numbers. What has your conservative extension to do with identifying natural numbers with equivalence classes of ordered pairs of natural numbers?

Comment: @rere The models of the theory $T$ are precisely those models that are obtained by starting with a model of PA and constructing the usual equivalence classes of ordered pairs from the model.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Well, I wasn't proposing this as a practical way to work but as a way of formalizing mathematical practice via a conservative extension, as the OP requested. I wonder if, when Tao mentioned *typed* first-order logic, he might really have meant what's usually called *many-sorted* first-order logic, with different variables specified as ranging over different domains. (I generally prefer to stick to the usual single-sorted models, since then you can build on so much more existing model theory. But conceptually they can be viewed as equivalent.)

Comment: And why should the extension that identifies the integer 3 with the natural number 3 be conservative? Shouldn't we allow that considering integers (or then also rationals and reals) leads to insights about natural numbers? For example, considering sets also leads to further insights about natural numbers (using ordinals we can prove Goodsteins theorem, but using just PA it doesnt work)

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Pls answer me

Comment: @rere Sorry, I haven't had much time for StackExchange -- I'll answer later today.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Thanks, I am looking forward to that.

Comment: Considering integers *doesn't* lead to any additional insights over considering natural numbers (unlike the example with sets of natural numbers, which, as you pointed out, *does* provide additional insight). The proof of that is as outlined in my answer: The theory $T$ encapsulates the first-order theory of the integers (just as PA encapsulates the first-order theory of the natural numbers), but $T$ doesn't prove any additional theorems about natural numbers beyond what PA already proved. (The rationals can be treated in a similar way. The situation with the reals is more complicated.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Thanks. Tao speaks about "a suitable conservative extension of the original mathematical theory". Why is it so important to him that the extension is conservative? Also, Tao works in his book with a set theory. How does one identify the integer 3 (which is a set) with the natural number 3 in a set theory?

Comment: Isn't it more important that the extension proves everything the original theory proved rather than the other way round?

Comment: "How does one identify the integer 3 (which is a set) with the natural number 3 in a set theory?" Via an appropriate translation. If you're working syntactically, every sentence about natural numbers in one language has a corresponding sentence in the 2nd language which intuitively has the same intended meaning and which formally is provable in the 2nd theory iff the original sentence is provable in the 1st theory. If you're working with actual models, then there's an isomorphism between the submodel of "natural numbers" in the 1st model with the submodel of "natural numbers" in the 2nd model.

Comment: @rere "Isn't it more important that the extension proves everything the original theory proved rather than the other way round?" $T$ above and PA prove exactly the same sentences about the natural numbers. I commented on the one direction simply as a demonstration that reasoning about the integers doesn't yield additional insights about the natural numbers, in reply to your earlier comment on that question.

Comment: @rere Well, of course I can't speak for Tao as to why it's important to him, but, with that said, the point of a conservative extension is that you can think of the two theories involved as being equivalent, under the appropriate translations. So it may be easier to reason in the apparently larger theory, but you can be sure that you're not making any foundational commitments stronger than the original smaller theory. Also, if you have a variety of theories, this lets you know that they really are all part of one common body of mathematics.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Do I understand it correctly that the main idea described by Terence Tao is this: in practice, we just act like the natural number 3 for example is equal to the integer 3; and any argument that involves such an identification can be carried out in a extension where the primitive objects are the integer and there is a subcollection of the integers which have all the properties we want natural numbers to have (sometimes this extension happens to be conservative: if we write down all the properties we want natural numbers to have, the extension yields to no new insights)?

Comment: @MitchellSpector: Do I understand this correctly? If yes, then I would accept your answer.

Comment: @rere Yes, that's correct. There's another subtext too: when we make a definition, pass to a conservative extension, etc., we're implicitly saying that we think that the new concept being developed is important and useful, and that organizing things around that idea will yield a productive perspective.